# MySQL: Replace a specific MySQL Value with an SQL Query

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a database with a column 'Date'.

At first, the person whom setup the database, he wrongly set the column Type to varchar(9).

The date's are **01-01-2012 (10 Characters)**, thus on every single date is missing the last number.

[image]

Is it possible now to replace all 201 with 2012 using a MySQL Query?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a DATE column type for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = REPLACE(columnName, '201', '2012')
```

OR

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = CONCAT(columnName, '2')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*two queries included*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01467/1)

Comment: CONCAT adds a value at the end?

Answer (score 0):

First increase the table size to varchar(10).  Then

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = REPLACE(columnName, '201', '2012')
```

Comment: Im using phpMyAdmin. I think I need to use `` ?
UPDATE `Fuelconsumption`
SET `date` = REPLACE(`date`, '201', '2012')

Comment: you will only use backtick if your column name is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) or has space on it, `hello world`

Comment: @jQuerybeast date isn't a reserved word in mysql, so no escaping needed